# Make a batch file that uses user input to ping an IP Address with a menu

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to make a CMD batch file that uses user input to ping a IP.

I also want to integrate the feature of using user input to ping an IP Address into a menu so that you can choose weather you want to ping the IP Address only 4 times or endlessly.

Comment: User input? https://superuser.com/questions/837344/how-to-accept-user-input-command-in-batch-file

Comment: I will try this thanks.

Comment: @cricket_007 Okay it works but not the way I want it to. All I want the user to do is type the IP Address and not the entire command, is there a way to make **set /p** run **ping -t .....**  so that when you type the IP Address out it runs **ping -t .....**

Comment: That's just accepting text. You can edit however you want. For example try `ping -t %CommandVar%`

Comment: Also, please don't delete your post again

Comment: Thanks, now I understand how the **set /p** works thanks a lot.

Comment: Okay I wont delete it.

Comment: Please read [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564) There is everything explained how to offer a menu from which a user can put an option or how to give the user the freedom to enter a string and safely process it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic script that will allow the user to input the IP they wish to PING. After the script runs, it will pause then loop back to user input again. Furthermore, the script will detect if a host exist's or not, prompt the user, then loop back to user input.

The command your looking for is `SET` with a syntax of `SET [variable=[string]]` The gate `/P` is `Prompt For Input`. This will allow the script to "ask" you something then can prompt it via the `%variable%`.

```
@ECHO OFF

:PING
cls & set /p adress=Type an adress you wish to ping: 
cls

ping %adress% & echo. & pause. & goto :PING
```

Comment: That is a working batch file as long as the batch file user really enters what this batch code expects from user input. But it is very unsafe and could also do unexpected things even on apparently correct entered strings like `216.072.213.228`. Why all those `&` operators instead of writing one command per command line? And I suggest to read DosTips forum topic [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774) and use in future `echo/` or `echo(` instead of `echo.` to output an empty line.